# Update Laravel Version to 8.0 From 7.x

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

**Im updating My laravel  Version to 8.0 From 7.x Through CMD Using Composer Command `composer update` but im getting errors**

```
 D:\xampp\htdocs\salebaba>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
    
      Problem 1
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.5.0
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.4.0
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.3.0
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.2.0
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.1.0
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.0.4
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.0.3
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.0.2
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.0.1
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.0.0
        - laravel/socialite v4.1.4 requires illuminate/support ~5.7.0|~5.8.0|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.36, v6.18.37, v6.18.38, v6.18.39, v6.18.4, v6.18.40, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
        - laravel/socialite v4.4.1 requires illuminate/support ~5.7.0|~5.8.0|^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.28.3, 6.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.36, v6.18.37, v6.18.38, v6.18.39, v6.18.4, v6.18.40, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.28.2, v7.28.3, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
        
        - laravel/socialite v4.1.3 requires illuminate/support ~5.7.0|~5.8.0|~5.9.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
        - laravel/socialite 4.1.1 requires illuminate/contracts ~5.7.0|~5.8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/contracts[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
   .
```

**Here is **`Composer.json`****

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
    "laravel/socialite": "^4.1",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.14",
    "rosell-dk/webp-convert": "^2.3",
    "srmklive/paypal": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
},
```

Comment: Which parts of that error message are unclear? What have you tried to resolve them?

Comment: @NicoHaase There was error in package version.. Thanks for reply but i have resolved my problem now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"require": {
"php": "^7.3",
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
"intervention/image": "^2.4",
"laravel/framework": "^8.0",
"laravel/socialite": "^4.1",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
"laravel/ui": "^3.0",
"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.14",
"rosell-dk/webp-convert": "^2.3",
"srmklive/paypal": "~1.0"},
```

Update the Above section with these....

```
"laravel/socialite": "^5.0",
```

Answer (score 3):

update this

```php
 "laravel/socialite": "^5.0",
```

then run `composer update`

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/releases/tag/v5.0.1 latest build which it support `laravel 8`

Answer (score 1):

The error says that your package installation list is in conflict, you're trying to install socialite v4 but that requires laravel v6. If you update to socialite v5 it should work

```
    "require": {
"php": "^7.3",
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
"intervention/image": "^2.4",
"laravel/framework": "^8.0",
"laravel/socialite": "^5.1",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
"laravel/ui": "^3.0",
"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.14",
"rosell-dk/webp-convert": "^2.3",
"srmklive/paypal": "~1.0"},
```